# delete and modify properties in array inside json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Given the following JSON:

```js
const myJson = {
    id: 8,
    active: true,
    invoice: "2022/1001",
    invoiceDate: "2022-02-02",
    clientId: 1,
    storeId: 1,
    total: 76.95,
    itens: [
        {
            id: 11,
            quantity: 2,
            price: 12.10,
            total: 24.20,
            productId: 1,
            invoiceId: 8
        },
        {
            id: 12,
            quantity: 5,
            price: 10.55,
            total: 52.75,
            productId: 2,
            invoiceId: 8
        }
    ]
};
```

I need a simple way to remove two attributes from the each item inside the 'itens' array, the properties are 'id' and 'invoiceId'. I also need to recalculate the 'total', coz I do not trust totally the source of the information, I rather multiply 'quantity' by 'price' myself.

I've produced this rather naive code:

```js
myJson.itens.forEach(item => {

  item.total =
     item.quantity * 
     item.price;

     delete item.id;
     delete item.invoiceId;
});
```

And it works rather fine, however, no way that it must be it. Looks too lame and laborious  to me. I'm exhausted googling for better ways of doing it.

Can it be done better?

Comment: Perfect is the enemy of good. let sleeping dogs lie

Answer (score 2):

Rather than mutating the original data, you could [*map*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) it to a new object

```js
const myJson = {"id":8,"active":true,"invoice":"2022/1001","invoiceDate":"2022-02-02","clientId":1,"storeId":1,"total":76.95,"itens":[{"id":11,"quantity":2,"price":12.1,"total":24.2,"productId":1,"invoiceId":8},{"id":12,"quantity":5,"price":10.55,"total":52.75,"productId":2,"invoiceId":8}]}

const newObject = {
  ...myJson, // keep the rest but map "itens"
  itens: myJson.itens.map(({ id, invoiceId, ...iten }) => ({
    ...iten, // everything except "id" and "invoiceId"
    total: iten.quantity * iten.price // recalc total
  }))
}

console.log("newObject:", newObject)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```